# wordpress code snippet to match shortcode with userid

Tags: php, wordpress

I just installed ultimate member on my wordpress install. works and looks good. 
Trying to integrate IBSCalendar with members' profiles so each member can have their own feed which can be added with a short code in their profiles.
So far I have two bits of information and have zero (zip, nada) idea how to proceed with this.

To get the user id

```
[pp-tabs field=id]
```

and then the shortcode for IBSCalendar

```
[ibs-calendar feed="1" ]
```

the developer for one of the plugins indicated that custom php code is needed to match user id with feed#.
Can someone help?
I have roughly 1000 members that will need to be matched with their own feed (i.e. user id 142 with feed 523)
thanks in advance